# ASP Menu control animated style scrolling to point on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, user-interface

I have just followed a tutorial that showed me how to use a script along with anchors to scroll down to a point on the current page using animation. Although this works fine my current website uses an ASP menu.

My question is can I animate the ASP menu in the same way as a regular anchor? I have looked online for tutorials but nothing I have come across seems to fit the bill.

Would it just be easier to recreate the menu using standard HTML and CSS?

Edit: Menu markup as requested.

```
                <div id="navigation">
                    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="nbottom"
                        DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="nbottomitem"
                        StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="ntop"> 
                    </asp:Menu>
                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the markup for your ASP menu? All .NET controls render out to regular html (i.e. a `<asp:Hyperlink />` renders an `<a>` tag). If you use standard html for your menu you will probably lose all server-side interactions with your menu (i.e. binding data to it)

Comment: Yes I understand I would have to re-do the menu. I wouldn't mind doing that to get the effect. However if it can be done with ASP then obviously I would prefer to carry on using the menu.